# Scheduling jobs divided into classes

Tags: java, algorithm, scheduling

There are 'n' different types of jobs, e.g. small letters, capital letters and numbers. Switching from one type of job to another is more time consuming (S) than switching to job from the same group (C) . Every job has its deadline and process time.

For example :

```
n = 3; (small letters, capital letters and numbers)
S = 5;
C = 1;
```

Job/Deadline/Process Time

a/5/2
   1/15/3
   b/20/4
   R/25/1

a,1,b,R : 2+(5)+3+(5)+4+(5)+1 = 25
a,b,1,R : 2+(1)+4+(5)+4+(5)+1 = 21

Is there any algorithm which solves that problem besides metaheuristic ?

Comment: If you want to avoid implementing the optimization algorithm (such as metaheuristics) yourself, you can reuse Java frameworks such as OptaPlanner (which has [a job Shop scheduling video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2zweB9JD7c)), Choco, JaCop, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is [Job-shop problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job-shop_problem) that is a generalization of the [traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) so it is NP-hard and doesn't have optimal algorithm.
Try [Job shop scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling) article as starting point of your research